# Space between table rows with rounded corners

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem. I want to get space between table rows and that rows had rounded corners. I can get space with border-collapse, but then I won't be able to get rows with rounded corners.

I have tried border-radius but it just won't work.

Is there any way to get these both things to work?

```
th {
    background-color: black;
    color: dimgray;
}

td {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 1em;
}
*/
tr {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Rows should look like that:

[image]

Comment: where is your code???

Comment: Use `border-spacing`, not `border-collapse`.

Comment: What about setting the margin to some value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to do that kind of thing:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

table td {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 160px;
  height: 30px;
}

table td:first-of-type{
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

table td:last-of-type{
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It works for any number of `td` cells per `tr`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to apply the border-radius style to the td elements, border-radius doesn't work on tr elements.
If your rows are made up of multiple cells, you can use td:first-child and td:last-child to style the first and last cells with a border-radius and leave the rest without rounded borders.

Answer (score 0):

You can set whatever you want to style it.... (like `width`,`height`,`background-color` ...)

```css
    table{
border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px 20px;
}

 
table td,table th {
 border: 1px solid black;
width:100px;
height:50px;
border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    
  </tr>
</table>
```